# Date format and date parsing in Ext.Js4

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, extjs, date-format

i'm reading some data to build a grid with ext.js4.1.3 It isn't difficult as long as i don't have to parse the date field of my json. It is formatted like this:

```
"2013-04-30 21:59:40"
```

So it should be the European way of writing the date with the time after.. But i don't have any idea of how to read it. My last approach is:

in the Model:

```
 fields: [
   {name: 'id'},
   {name: 'name',      type: 'string', convert: null,     defaultValue: undefined},
   {name: 'email',     type: 'string', convert: null,     defaultValue: undefined},
   {name: 'last_modified',      type: 'date',  dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia', defaultValue: undefined}
],
```

(and i think that this is the dateformat which is messing up everything)

and in the Panel:

```
{
            text     : 'last_modified',
            width    : 85,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'last_modified'
        },
```

What am i missing? It is only a problem of recognizing the right dateformat? If i leave this configuration it recognizes the date field but doesn't display anything in it.As if the resulting field was undefined.Do you know if i should use an alternative dateformat at least in the model??

Agnese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have it setup correctly, except for using the wrong value for `dateFormat`.  This should be the value of the format coming in, so that the model can be saved correctly.  The format of `2013-04-30 21:59:40` should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

So, use this for your field definition:

```
{name: 'last_modified', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}
```